# Ошибка в библиотеке aiogram

Tags: python, telegram-bot, telegram, aiogram

Код:

```py
def admin_moderate_command(command: str):
    def decorator(func):
        @admin_command(command)
        async def handle(event: Message):
            if not event.is_reply:
                await event.respond('Пожалуйста, напишите эту команду в ответ на сообщение пользователя')
                return

        reply_to = await event.get_reply_message()

        if reply_to.sender.bot:
            await event.respond('Эту команду нельзя применять к ботам')
            return

        if await is_admin(event.chat.id, reply_to.sender.id):
            await event.respond('Эту команду нельзя применять к админам')
            return

        result = await func(event.chat.id, reply_to.sender_id, get_mention(reply_to.sender))
        await event.respond(result)

        return handle
    return decorator
```

Ошибка:

> SyntaxError: 'await' outside async functio

Что делать?

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Comment: Исправить ошибку

Comment: Приведите [mcve] с внятным описанием проблемы, а не одним лишь огрызком текста ошибки

Comment: Как минимум сразу видно, что у вас декоратор не асинхронный, из чего автоматически следует, что использовать await в нём нельзя

Comment: (ну и ошибка разумеется не в библиотеке aiogram, а в вашем коде, а ещё полный бардак с отступами)